# Connecting NodeJS MongoClient to localhost mongodb with Docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, dockerfile

macOS Sierra

MongoDB Enterprise > db.version() => 3.4.7

Node.js 8.9.0

Docker Image Inspect => [gist](https://gist.github.com/idkjs/a2279d5997c397533a80061ca4d94d7e)

I have this code that ran yesterday in Node then in a Docker container, doesn't run today in the Docker container with the following container error output. The errors references a topology issue which was triggered by something between yesterday and today. I dont know what that means. The only thing I can think of was switching nvm from 8.2.1 to 8.9.0. Switching back didn't help. Adding reconnect parameters also did not help. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Update: If I change the uri to the azure cosmosdb instance, it same code runs. So its just the connection string to the local mongodb that doesn't want to connect. Again, ran yesterday, was just updating. No idea what is going on here....

```
Hi mongodb://localhost:27017/visafrenchtech
MongoDB connecting to mongodb://localhost:27017/visafrenchtech
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:187:49)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
```

The Node.js Output is

```
Hi mongodb://localhost:27017/visafrenchtech
MongoDB connecting to mongodb://localhost:27017/visafrenchtech
DB mongodb://localhost:27017/visafrenchtech connected
{ _id: 59f8ab91277b785b1c354f05,
  url: 'http://visa.lafrenchtech.com/10/find-your-future-employer-in-france-french-tech-visa',
  logo: 'https://d25e16a427ed3ce77d27-76b466cd72f6b3a6e7219a8a02851d8e.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/files/59382428ff3935425ca91516/size_5_1001pharmaciesjpg.jpg',
  company_url: 'http://www.1001pharmacies.com/',
  company_name: '1001 Pharmacies',
  industry: '#HealthTech #Retail',
  location: 'French Tech Montpellier',
  number_employees: 28,
  description: '1001Pharmacies.com is a marketplace dedicated to the online sale of health / beautyproducts. We are intermediaries between Internet users and French pharmacies for online sales.',
  job_offers: 'Job Offers',
  job_offers_link: 'http://www.welcometothejungle.co/companies/1001pharmacies',
  Twitter: '@1001pharma',
  Facebook: 'https://www.facebook.com/1001Pharmacies/',
  Instagram: 'https://www.instagram.com/1001pharmacies/?hl=fr',
  Youtube: 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChLwpSs9nHs2xbYdbNEJqQg',
  address: 'Parc Eureka 256 r Thor, 34000 MONTPELLIER',
  tranche: '21 - 40' }
```

This is the DockerFile

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:8
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "node", "index.js"]
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? Also where is mongodb is running?

Comment: Have you exposed the mongo port if your mongo is running on docker?

Comment: macOS, Sierra.@TarunLalwani. MongoClient connects to MongoDB running on local machine per Node output snippet.